# Как получить значение тега вложенного элемента?

Tags: c#, unity3d, xml

Есть xml-файл с элементом `<casdo:ProcedureCode >78</casdo:ProcedureCode>`,
который есть где-то вначале документа:

```
<casdo:ProcedureCode >78</casdo:ProcedureCode>
```

и есть где-то в середине документа:

```
<cacdo:ProcedureDetails>
  <casdo:ProcedureCode >78</casdo:ProcedureCode>
</cacdo:ProcedureDetails>
```

Правда, во втором случае он вложен в другой элемент.

Использую `XmlTextReader` для парсинга. Считываю значение "78" и передаю его объекту Text. И вот тут проблема: если бы тег `casdo:ProcedureCode` в документе повторялся бы один раз, проблем бы не было.

Как мне исключить считывание значения тега первого (невложенного) элемента, т.е. reader должен проигнорировать первый тег casdo:ProcedureCode, а второй считать?

Весь код примерно такой:

```
public Text text;     
public void LoadData()
{
    if (File.Exists("C:/Users/xml/1.xml"))
    {
        XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("C:/Users/xml/1.xml");
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.IsStartElement() && !reader.IsEmptyElement)
            {
                switch (reader.Name)
                {
                    ...
                    case "casdo:ProcedureCode": // как добавить условие, что "и этот элемент вложен в  cacdo:ProcedureDetails"?
                        text.text = reader.ReadString();

                        break;
                }
            }

        }
        reader.Close();
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("указанный файл или путь к нему не существует!");
    }
```

Comment: Это обязательное условие - использовать потоковый XmlReader? Работать с xml в памяти существенно проще в вашем случае. Если размер xml не превышает сотни мегабайт, переходите на LinqToXml.

Comment: Я думала об этом, и даже реализовала все тоже самое через XmlDocument Class. Но, дело в том, что я не уверена, что файлы не будут  большими (ибо по закон-ву в одном файле может содержаться информация о 999 товарах!!!). + В дальнейшем хотелось бы создать версию приложения для смартфонов, не хотелось бы потом переписывать куски кода

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хорошо бы знать, какие ещё данные вы получаете из этого файла.

Если нужно просто получить значение из узла `ProcedureCode`, вложенного в узел `ProcedureDetails`, то это делается элементарно так:

```
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create("test.xml"))
{
    if (reader.ReadToFollowing("cacdo:ProcedureDetails"))
    {
        reader.ReadToFollowing("casdo:ProcedureCode");
        var text = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
        Console.WriteLine(text);
    }
}
```

Обратите внимание: `XmlReader` создаётся вызовом метода `Create` - это рекомендованный в документации способ вместо использования устаревшего класса `XmlTextReader`.

Сам ридер обёрнут в конструкцию `using` - это автоматически вызовет метод `Dispose`, что закроет ридер и освободит все ресурсы, даже в случае исключения.

`XmlReader` имеет множество полезных методов. Один из них `ReadToFollowing` - он перемещает нас сразу к нужному элементу.

---

Однако, думаю, вам нужно не просто пропускать элементы по пути к нужному, но как-то их обрабатывать.

Можно использовать дополнительную переменную-флаг.

```
bool insideProcedureDetails = false;

using (var reader = XmlReader.Create("test.xml"))
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (reader.IsStartElement())
        {
            switch (reader.Name)
            {
                case "cacdo:ProcedureDetails":
                    insideProcedureDetails = true;
                    break;

                case "casdo:ProcedureCode":
                    if (insideProcedureDetails)
                    {
                        var text = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                        Console.WriteLine(text);
                        insideProcedureDetails = false;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

> получить значение из узла ProcedureCode, вложенного в узел ProcedureDetails, вложенного в узел Procedure

Всё то же самое. Просто добавляем ещё одну булеву переменную и ещё одну ветку `case`.

```
bool insideProcedure = false;
bool insideProcedureDetails = false;

using (var reader = XmlReader.Create("test.xml"))
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (reader.IsStartElement())
        {
            switch (reader.Name)
            {
                case "Procedure":
                    insideProcedure = true;
                    break;

                case "cacdo:ProcedureDetails":
                    insideProcedureDetails = true;
                    break;

                case "casdo:ProcedureCode":
                    if (insideProcedure && insideProcedureDetails)
                    {
                        var text = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                        Console.WriteLine(text);
                        insideProcedure = false;
                        insideProcedureDetails = false;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо большое!

Comment: подскажите, а если есть еще одна или несколько вложенностей, к примеру, нужно получить значение из узла ProcedureCode, вложенного в узел ProcedureDetails, вложенного в узел Procedure?

Comment: @Volha - дополнил ответ.

Comment: спасибо, буду думать, изучать. Я реализовала чтение двойной вложенности через if else (как в первом предложенном вами варианте), и у меня не получилось, видимо, где-то ошиблась. Опыта у меня пока очень мало. Буду пробовать через флаги.